# Run a script when workspace changed

Tags: perforce

I'm working on a virtual hard disk in order to imitate a production setup and each workspaces that I'm using correspond to one folder which I mount into the virtual hard disk.

That's why I would like to have a script which change automatically the folder regarding of the choosen workspace.

Does someone have any ideas how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Colin

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`P4CONFIG`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4CONFIG.html).

The idea of P4CONFIG in a nutshell is that it allows you to associate each local folder with a client configuration (i.e. `P4CLIENT`, and potentially `P4USER`, `P4PORT`, etc).  Issuing a `p4` command from a given folder automatically switches your configuration to that provided by the `P4CONFIG` file in (or above) that folder.

This is the standard way of working with multiple workspaces (or servers) on one client machine without having to continually update your settings.

In the context of a virtual drive that you're remounting, you'd put the `P4CONFIG` file in the root of the target folder, and then when you remount (e.g. via `subst`), the appropriate config file appears in the root of the mounted folder, whereupon all your `p4` commands recognize that the workspace has changed.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for.
I'm using the same virtual disk for all my workspaces, I just remap the project folder to the virtual disk when I have to switch workspaces. I do that to imitate the production process and I can't change that.
So, I would like my perforce to run a script whenever I change workspace.
Is it possible with P4Config ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing.  Do the workspaces all share the exact same local files on the same disk, or are they different folders within the virtual disk, such that you have a different set of local files each time you "remap the project folder" (I'm not sure what that means -- remounting a different folder to the same local filesystem mount point)?

Comment: All workspaces have different folders but I mount them into the same virtual disk.
Example :
My virtual disk is T.
If I choose workspace A, I want my script to mount folder A into T.
If I change to workspace B, I want to mount folder B into T.

Comment: How do you "choose" workspaces?  How do you mount the folders?  Could you just put P4CONFIG files in the folders and then choose a workspace by mounting the appropriate folder?

Comment: I choose workspaces by switching workspace in P4V.
I mount them using windows subst.
I don't got your last sentence sorry.

Comment: Ah -- if you were launching a client from the CLI, you could use `P4CONFIG` and then switch workspaces in a single step via `subst` (i.e. when you remount the local drive, your settings just automatically change based on the config file in the folder you mounted).  With P4V I don't think you can automate it that way, because it's not going to refresh its config from the working directory the way the CLI would; you'll probably want to add a custom tool that you can trigger manually after switching workspaces.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I already have something to trigger it manually but I was hopping that I could have it automatically.

Comment: Nope -- if there were a way to do it it'd be via P4VJS, but I don't see any supported functions there for being able to switch connections (or trigger an action on the connection being switched).  https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4vjs-ug/Content/P4VJS-UG/functions-supported.html